# How to write a WPF async unit test for a method that uses Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mstest, dispatcher

We have an application written in WPF.
I'm trying to write a unit test for some code that runs on background threads. On a few place in this code we need to do things on the UI thread. In those places we use the following code structure:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
// do something on UI thread
}));
```

When I create an async unit test it seems to get stuck on the Invoke method. I guess this is because the dispatcher is not "dispatching". I've tried to fix this by using a class called DisaptcherUtil that is referenced in a number of places on the internet. But I can't get this to work. A simplistic version of my code now looks like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestDispatcher()
    {
        new Application();

        DispatcherUtil.DoEvents();

        await Task.Run(() => MethodUsingDispatcher());
    }


    private void MethodUsingDispatcher()
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On the dispatchee thread!");
        }));

        Console.WriteLine("BAck to background trhead");
    }

    public static class DispatcherUtil
    {
        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
                new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
        }

        private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExitFrame");

            ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I run the test called "TestDispatcher" it just hangs.

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Is this the right way to do this or should I instead go down the route of creating an interface for the Dispatcher that I could mock in the tests. I've seen this done in some places.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991877/mvvm-light-dispatcher-unit-tests/38994745#38994745

Comment: You shouldn't call any static methods in your testable classes. Inject the class with an interface that defines an `Invoke` method and call the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method through this interface instead of calling the static `Dispatcher.Invoke` method directly. You could easily replace the implementatin of the interface in your unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you should hide the dispatching behind an interface and mock it in the unit tests:

```
interface IDispatcher
{
    void Dispatch(Action action);
}
```

You can easily mock this in your tests and expect to those dispatched calls.

An implementation which uses the real dispatcher and can be used by your app:

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    public void Dispatch(Action action)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it works fine. 
I used https://www.zuehlke.com/blog/en/mvvm-and-unit-testing/ which contians a very similar solution to the one above.
Strange that DisaptcherUtil seem to be recommended in a number of places.